# Applying successive shaders to a texture while keeping float precesion

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, shader, shaderlab

I have a render texture in Unity and am applying successive shaders to it as following:

```
     Graphics.Blit(Tex1, Tex2, myMaterialA);
     Graphics.Blit(Tex2, Tex3, myMaterialB);
     Graphics.Blit(Tex3, Tex4, myMaterialC);
```

In my shaders, I only work with floats, but the outputed color values get quantified on 8 bits since the output texture is RGBA 32 bits.

**In my example, is there a way to keep float precisions for the intermediate results (Tex2, Tex3) and only convert the final texture Tex4 to RGB 32bits ?**

Comment: You should refrain from asking multiple questions within a Question, it tends to get your Question closed as "too broad."

Comment: @Draco18s Alright, I edited my post to make it more concise and kept only one question.

Answer (score 0):

Both Texture2D and RenderTexture can have different format than ARGB32.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTextureFormat.html